# Preview uploaded images in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display a set of uploaded images on the page but something goes wrong. So, my code creates separated div for every uploaded image and sets every image as background-image of every div. The problem is that only last div gets its image and others remain empty.

Here is my code:

```
showImages(e.dataTransfer.files);
function showImages(files) {

    const imagesdiv = document.getElementById('imagess')

    Array.from(files).forEach(file => {

        const reader = new FileReader();

        mydiv = document.createElement('div');
        mydiv.classList.add('imagein');

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = () => {mydiv.style.backgroundImage = `url('${reader.result}')`;};

        imagesdiv.appendChild(mydiv);

    });
}
```

Comment: The variable mydiv in reader.onload doesn't refer to "the right div".  Assign your mydiv variable using `let` -> `let mydiv = document.createElement('div');`

Comment: With regard to today's question, I don't believe you can set the files on an <input type="file"> (other than through user interaction). Afaik, existing solutions like DropZone keep their own array of files, and only use the input temporarily to display the file selection window. They ultimately append the array of files to a FormData object and upload using AJAX.

Comment: @Chris G, thank you a lot! I was really surprised to discover that someone is still ready to help me. I will try out DropZone. I just thought that it is possible to add files in input element when user drags and drops it

Comment: @Chris G, but I guess that it is still somehow achievable. As it would be bad practice to post huge chunk of code in comments, please take a look at the code in video on 22:52 https://youtu.be/Wtrin7C4b7w . There we can see that author assigns dropped images to input element, and chances are, it is possible to add images to input element not directly, but getting the file list from input and adding images to this file list and then setting the value of input to this list. I hope, I expressed my idea clearly

Comment: I was able to get this to work in the sense that the dropped files are selected in the <input>, however your original question was about *appending* them I believe? I.e. if I drop multiple single files over the dropzone,  the input selection keeps growing?

Comment: _if I drop multiple single files over the dropzone, the input selection keeps growing?_
-Yes, that's actually I was trying to do...

Comment: I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16742956/file-field-append-file-list which seems to confirm my first comment: appending to the <input> is not possible, but displaying a growing list of files and uploading it via ajax is absolutely possible